# Cloudpage preference center reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm noticing that there's not a report or capability to see how users are interacting with our preference center other than visits and clicks (non-specific).  Is there a place that I'm not looking that contains this data?

Think that I might have to use a 3rd party like HotJar do get a better look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of visits that you can see in the summary, there isnt a native cloud page reporting tool. Most clients I have worked with use good ol Google Analytics tags, but I assume adobe or any third party will do

Comment: Thanks - Just needed the confirmation.  We are using GTM and I'll just go that route.  Hopefully it get's updated some day and lightens the load on cross-tool referencing for me...

Comment: With Salesforce's Google partnership..that light might just be at the end of the tunnel

Comment: Will be a 3 year long tunnel though